# JQuery value not saving?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, var

I have two divs when clicked on it saves the ID value into a variable, this value is saving to a variable but is undefined when running other function.

Pleases take a look it should make more sense .

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/L0jm5c95/1/)

```
//Setting the click amount
var ClickedAmount = 1
    //On a note click run...
$(".note").click(function() {
    //If Click amount == 2 run
    if (ClickedAmount == 2) {
        //Alert NoteOne - This should be a value
        alert(NoteOne);
    };
    //If Click amount is == 1 run
    if (ClickedAmount == 1) {
        //Get the ID of the element that was clicked on and
        //replace note id with nothing.
        var NoteClicked = this.id.replace('note', '');
        //NoteOne - Now == the Divs number id Selected. 
        var NoteOne = NoteClicked
        alert(NoteOne);
        //Clicked amount added so other if statements runs on next click
        ClickedAmount++;
    };
})
```

Any suggestions thanks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0jm5c95/2/).

The NoteOne variable is a local variable in a function. Once the function execution is over, the variable is forgotten. If you want to persist the value, make the variable global.

```
var NoteOne = null;
//Setting the click amount
var ClickedAmount = 1
    //On a note click run...
$(".note").click(function() {
    //If Click amount == 2 run
    if (ClickedAmount == 2) {
        //Alert NoteOne - This should be a value
        alert(NoteOne);
    };
    //If Click amount is == 1 run
    if (ClickedAmount == 1) {
        //Get the ID of the element that was clicked on and
        //replace note id with nothing.
        var NoteClicked = this.id.replace('note', '');
        //NoteOne - Now == the Divs number id Selected. 
        NoteOne = NoteClicked
        alert(NoteOne);
        //Clicked amount added so other if statements runs on next click
        ClickedAmount++;
    };
})
```

Comment: Thanks for all your response makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

The variable `NoteOne` will be hoisted to the top. As a result it is displaying undefined. If you want to make it working as per your expectation then move that `NoteOne` variable declaration outside of the event listener. In other words move it to the lexical scope of that event listener.

```
var NoteOne;
var ClickedAmount = 1
$(".note").click(function() {
.
.
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/L0jm5c95/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `NoteOne` outside of your functions:

```js
//Setting the click amount
var ClickedAmount = 1
var NoteOne;

//On a note click run...
$(".note").click(function() {

  //If Click amount == 2 run
  if (ClickedAmount == 2) {
    //Alert NoteOne - This should be a value
    alert(NoteOne);
  };

  //If Click amount is == 1 run
  if (ClickedAmount == 1) {

    //Get the ID of the element that was clicked on and
    //replace note id with nothing.
    var NoteClicked = this.id.replace('note', '');

    //NoteOne - Now == the Divs number id Selected. 
    NoteOne = NoteClicked

    alert(NoteOne);

    //Clicked amount added so other if statements runs on next click
    ClickedAmount++;

  };
})
```

```css
.note {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">

  <div id="note1" class="note">Note 1</div>
  <div id="note2" class="note">Note 2</div>

  <!-- The input section, user clicks this to login on. -->
  <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login">

</form>
```